# Importing a file in R which has column names in first physical column

Tags: r, file, xlsx, data-import

How should I import an [xlsx](/questions/tagged/xlsx) file that has column names in the first physical column? For example, I have something like the below.

```
A  1  4  6
B  5  7  9
C  7  6  9
```

The conventional placement of this data is the following, and it is also how I want the data to look after the import.

```
A B C
1 5 7
4 7 6
6 9 9
```

It is easy to read the conventional placement, but I don't know how to read the file if the placement has the column names in a column. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `read.csv` to read the entire file as-is, then use appropriate subsetting.

```
df <- read.csv(file="input.csv")
name_vec <- df[,1]
df <- data.frame(t(df[,2:ncol(df)]))
names(df) <- name_vec
df

   A B C
v2 1 5 7
v3 4 7 6
v4 6 9 9
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c("A", "B", "C"), v2=c(1,5,7), v3=c(4,7,6), v4=c(6,9,9),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you. The matrix in your output is not the desired output. Please see the second matrix in my question for the desired output. The input is the first matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose df is the data frame you read from the xlsx file.

Then you can transpose it with `t()`

```
df <- t(df)
```

You will obtain something like this

```
V1 "A"  "B"  "C" 
V2 "1"  "5"  "7" 
V3 "4"  "7"  "6" 
V4 "6"  "9"  "9"
```

Now you fetch the names from the first row and remove it.

```
mynames <- df[1,]
df <- as.data.frame(df[-1,])
```

Now you assign those column names, and remove row names.

```
colnames(df) <- mynames
rownames(df) <- NULL
```

Result

```
  A B C
1 1 5 7
2 4 7 6
3 6 9 9
```